# Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I am new to spring boot and gradle and trying to install the required dependencies, however the video i am watching is using an older version of gradle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE')
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
}


group 'com.teamtreehouse'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have tried using apply plugin but it does not seem to work. I am expecting to be able to run gradle build without any issues

Answer (score 0):

Try add to settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

and pass version to plugins section:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
```

Comment: there is no pluginmanagement

Comment: using Gradle 7.5.1

Comment: So try "add" this section to settings.gradle

Comment: what? do you have an example?

Comment: pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'course-reviews-api' builds with error below

Comment: getting error Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:.
     Required by:

Comment: So this worked - and now You have another problem with dependencies

Comment: Try add "apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'" below your plugins section

Comment: perfect thanks. Do you know of a step by step guide for dependency management using gradle?

Comment: gradle documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: Or use https://start.spring.io/ to initalize your projects - then basic configs will be ready

Comment: @udacity-training if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: i want to understand it under the hood, i come from .net where you have to do this stuff yourself